# How to get user current in asp.net ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis-7.5

I search more time about this in here. When i tested in local , it's wworking, sample get user current `JoinHenry - ABC\JoinHenry - ABC\JoinHenry` , but when publish in remote server , it's not working , get `DefaultAppPool - - IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` . I dont' known how to fix it , I try with more case for this, sample

```
 string test1 = Environment.UserName;
 string test2 = User.Identity.Name;
 string test3 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
 string current = test1  + " - " +  test2  + " - " + test3 ;
```

I try add in web.config `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`  . And setting in IIS server `Anonymous Authentication = Disable , Window Authentication = Enable`  and change DefaultAppPool  set at `Identity = ApplicationPoolIdentity` . But it's not working .
Give a adviced for this .

Answer (score -1):

Use `HttpContext.Current.User` if you want to get the logged in user.

Comment: This is no different that using `User` directly

Comment: Get the user current login window , not login web page .